# Regex everything after x until space

Tags: javascript, regex

Take `xnum-539 classname random-word xnum-hello hi-239`.

I need to pick out anything that is after `xnum-`, so in this case the `539`, and `hello`.

I have tried multiple things and the best I've got to is either:

`-(.*?)\s`.
But that includes the dash when I only want what's after the dash. (ex `-539`)

or

`rnum-(.*?)\s` which takes the whole thing.

For both solutions I don't want to have to manually slice.
Apologies if this is a duplicate but I've tried to work with other answers and well I'm terrible at regex.

Thanks

Comment: Is the example the extent of your data, or could there be an arbitrary number of `xnum-` entries?  Never mind, Wiktor's answer has you covered :-)

Comment: Actually, there is little one can do here, you just cannot use a plain `String#match` or `RegExp#exec` call since JS regex engine does not support a lookbehind. So, choose between slicing or running `RegExp#exec` inside a loop.

Comment: Unknown number of `xnum-` entries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note your regex actually requires a whitespace (`\s`) at the end of the match, thus, stopping the regex engine to match your value at the end  of the string.

You may get all matches with [`/xnum-(\S+)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/TIuIpa/1) regex and access group 1:

```js
var s = "xnum-539 classname random xnum-hello";
var res=[],m;
var re = /xnum-(\S+)/g;
while ((m=re.exec(s)) !== null) {
  res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```

**Pattern details**:

- `xnum-` - a sequence of literal chars `xnum-`
- `(\S+)`  - Capturing group with ID 1 matching one or more non-whitespace symbols.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Is there any way to get it in a one liner? I will be putting the regex in a `document.getElementsByClassName(REGEXHERE)' which itself is inside a loop. Thanks

Comment: No, I already explained in the comment to the question. I doubt you will be able to pass a regex to `getElementByClassName` though.